# Accessing Selected Value from a Pulldown menu

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu, forms

I am having trouble in accessing the selected value from a dropdown menu. When I try to access the value selected in the javascript function displayPhoto, no value is being accessed at all (I tried to print it out in a textfield). Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Here is the HTML part:

```
<form id="colorChoice">
    <img id="photo" src="red.jpg" alt="red" />
    <select name="color" size=5>
         <option value="red" onclick="jsFunction()">Red</option>
         <option value="blue" onclick="jsFunction()">Blue</option>
         ...
    </select>
</form>
```

(I have tried this for **'onclick'** and **'onchange'**, both doesn't work.)

Here is the Javascript part:

```
function jsFunction(){
    var imageFile; = document.getElementById("colorChoice").color.value + ".jpg";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer, I realized the mistake, it's the stupid ';' I had after 'imageFile'

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `onchange` on the `select` element.

```
<form id="colorChoice">
    <img id="photo" src="red.jpg" alt="red" />
    <select name="color" id="color" size="5" onchange="jsFunction()">
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         ...
    </select>
</form>
```

ther is also a `;` in your function infront of imageFile

```
function jsFunction(){
 var imageFile = document.getElementById('color').value + '.jpg';
 alert(imageFile);
}
```

Comment: you put 'onchange' on the 'select' element? read the answer again.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, the stupid ';' before the imageFile is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your Html Part be like that

```
<form id="colorChoice">
    <img id="photo" src="red.jpg" alt="red" />
    <select name="color" size="5" onchange="jsFunction()">
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="blue">Blue</option>
         ...
    </select>
</form>
```

and you jscript part would be like that

```
function jsFunction(){
    var imageFile = document.getElementById("colorChoice").color.value + ".jpg";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select an item by "name" attribute when you are using getElementById. Rather set an ID for the select tag, like so:

```
    <form id="colorChoice">
        <img id="photo" src="red.jpg" alt="red" />
        <select id="color" size="5" onchange="jsFunction()">
             <option value="red">Red</option>
             <option value="blue">Blue</option>
             ...
        </select>
    </form>
```

And then have your js as follows:

```
function jsFunction(){
    var imageFile = document.getElementById("color").value + ".jpg";
    ...
}
```

Also note that I have taken the onchange() event as the above answers suggest.